# how to use DISTINCT here in my query CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, distinct

```
$q = $this->db->select('
             books.title,
             reserved_books.id,
             reserved_books.isbn, 
             reserved_books.price,
             reserved_books.item_sold,
             reserved_books.date_sold,
             reserved_books.total_amount
            ')
        ->from('reserved_books')
        ->join('books','reserved_books.isbn= books.isbn')
        ->limit($limit,$offset);
```

how can i use distinct here in my query? 
reserved_books.isbn is the unique one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try Below:

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

but Distinct will not always work. You should add -`>group_by("name_of_the_column_which_needs_to_be unique");`

```
$this->db->group_by('column_name');
```

Comment: you are right distinct wont work in my code.. i used $this->db->distinct(); above my select but not working

Comment: How would you write this to select distinct from one column?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any join

```
 $query=$this->db->distinct()->select('table_attribute')->where('condition')->get('table_name');
  return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Adds the "DISTINCT" keyword to a query before Select**

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

[Refrence](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: I used it with jerremy's MY_Model. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this

```
$select =   array(
             'books.title',
             'reserved_books.id',
             'DISTINCT reserved_books.isbn', 
             'reserved_books.price',
             'reserved_books.item_sold',
             'reserved_books.date_sold',
             'reserved_books.total_amount'
);
$q = $this->db
        ->select($select)
        ->from('reserved_books')
        ->join('books','reserved_books.isbn= books.isbn')
        ->group_by('reserved_books.isbn')
        ->limit($limit,$offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is best way to remove duplicate entry.

```
$query  =  $this->db->select("inf.id, inf.sku, inf.fab_id, inf.sku, inf.amount, inf.min_length, inf.num_of_pieces, inf.width ,inf.type") 
                            ->join("retailcat","retailcat.sku=SUBSTRING(inf.sku,1,19) AND retailcat.category=218","INNER") 
                            ->distinct()
                           ->get("input_factor inf");
```