# count number of rows with detail through query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am making a travel agency website in codeigniter. I am getting destination of africa from my database and displaying on a page. 
here is my code of controller:

```
public function africa() {
    $data['africa']= $this->Travel->africa_des();
    $this->load->view('africa', $data);
}
```

my Model:

```
function africa_des() {
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->like('region', 'africa');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query= $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I want to get total number of flights of each destination that i have in my database. For instance I have 25 flights of Abuja so I want to get that number with Abuja destination.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Did u try using  `GROUP BY`  destination?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public function africa_desc(){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->where('region', 'africa');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `$this->db->distinct()` you must use `$this->db->group_by('column_name')` see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19509869/6098616. In your case I will assume that `destination` is your column name.

```html
public function africa_desc(){    
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->group_by('destination');
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->where('region', 'africa');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: and how i will get total number in my view page??

Answer (score 0):

Try this to count flights

```
public function africa_desc(){    
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->group_by('destination');
$this->db->from('travels_detail');
$this->db->where('region', 'africa');
$this->db->limit(5);
$query= $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();
```

}

Comment: I also need data, it will return only number of rows